# Div Content Does Not Render After Display Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not sure my problem is titles says but When I change the Display: None element to Display: Block, divs not rendering I think. JS files not overwriting the divs. And images not displaying. But when I use the visibility:hidden and visibility: visible feature its works fine. Here my files;

```
  <div id="gnc2"class="row">
    <div class="col s3 offset-s1">
      <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="galeri/gizemler/1.jpg" alt="Gizemler">
    <div class="caption">
      <h5 class="center-align">Gizemler</h5>
      <p class="center-align">Serideki mitler, gizemler</p>
      <p class="center-align"><a id="nbg2" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Ateşle</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="nbg1">
    <div class="main-gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true, "prevNextButtons": false, "pageDots": false }'>
      <img src="galeri/gizemler/1.jpg" />
      <img src="galeri/gizemler/2.jpg" />
      <img src="galeri/gizemler/3.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my script;

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#nbg2').click(function() {
        $("#gnc2").css("display","none");
        $("#nbg1").css("display","block");
      });
      </script>
```

CSS;

```
#nbg1 {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: `$('#nbg2').click(function()...` is this function actually being called?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/e739ehvy/ Perhaps create an [MCVE](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should really put your jQuery code between this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nbg2').click(function() {
      $("#gnc2").css("display","none");
      $("#nbg1").css("display","block");
   });
}
```

This way you make sure the whole page is properly loaded before applying javascript.

Then, i don't know what your flickity library do exactly but if it plays with your #nbg1 width and height values it may have trouble redefining them if the content of this div is not displayed at all (display: none). If you're forced to use this library while it has no callback method, i suggest you give this trick a try :

In your CSS :

```
#nbg1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

In your JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#nbg1").css("visibility","visible");
        $("#nbg1").hide();
        $('#nbg2').click(function() {
            $("#gnc2").hide();
            $("#nbg1").show();
        });           
    }, 200);
});
```

You can use this and play with the delay value (here 200). If your flickity library has some "job done" callback method, i suggest you use this one instead of the timeout trick i wrote here.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its still same. One thing I notice images shown after i click the inpect element feature in chrome.

Comment: Actually i made a mistake : i copied and pasted your css code and forgot to edit it. You should try to apply visibility:hidden to your #nbg1.

Comment: No problem. Just have in mind that it's just a trick. You should try using jquery plugins that have callbacks methods whenever it's possible. Have a good day. Bye !